# Xcode 6.1 doesn't recognize Foundation Classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

I'm newbie in Apple developing, but im trying to develop an osx applications. I have yosemite as OS and Xcode 6.1 as IDE. Everything was ok 3 days, but at some random moment, my Xcode showed me this:

[image: xcode goes crazy]

Everything covers with an errors.

What i did trying to resolve the problem:

1. Clean
2. Clean build folder
3. Delete derived data (in Organizer menu)
4. Reinstall Xcode
5. I even install Xcode 5 (but it don't support swift)

That erros follow me even in NEW project (with just one class AppDelegate.swift) and in any new class with any object like NS*.

What's happen with my Xcode and how i can fix it?

I forget to say, my project building and compiling without any error or warning. All errors disappears when i press button "Build".

**UPDATE #1:** i made: `import Foundation` - open it, and i did not find errors classes there. There are a lot of classes, such as NSCache and etc, but there are no NSTextField and etc.. Where are they?

**UPDATE #2:**

I've found that Xcode see classes which directly contains in Foundation moduel.
Also i got this window:
[image]

Comment: Make sure you're using a .m file and not a .c file.

Comment: What about your precompiled header file?  Is that properly defined?

Comment: @HotLicks can you give me more details about what I have to do please?